# How to make my Discord bot come online

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So I've been having trouble with my Discord bot on Visual Studio 2015, C#. I've just started out literally 5 minutes ago and I've come across a problem that I've looked at but just can't seem to find out the problem with. It's saying that

```
await discord.Connect("code here")
```

> should be a Username and password, or a token

But when I put my token in it says it needs two arguments.

Here is my code:

[image]

I've also tried putting

```
await discord.Connect("Client ID", "Secret");
```

But it's just not working. Sorry if I'm not giving enough information, or if mine just isn't good enough, but please. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: `Sorry if I'm not giving enough information` You can start by posting your code here, not an image...

Comment: Your error message says `it needs two arguments` but you post an **image** where you call it with **one** argument...

Comment: That's because if you if you look at the arguments, there's actually one there already.

Comment: @Omega But `discord.Connect` needs 2 :) Pass two arguments and update your question accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what .Net lib version you are using, in the one you are using, you have to specify the `TokeType` like so:

```
await discord.Connect("mytoken", TokenType.Bot)
```

Answer (score 0):

simple mistake. Having a Discord Bot myself, I ran into the same issue. The API is constantly getting updated, so what you've dont use to be right, here's how you can fix it:

```
try
{
    discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
    {
        await discord.Connect("Token", TokenType.Bot);   
    });
}
catch
{

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The method you are using is no longer working.

In 1.0 you should be using like this:

```
string token = "YOUR TOKEN";
await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
await _client.StartAsync();
```

Comment: I can see you calling methods which can be seen nowhere in the question. So how is that supposed to solve the problem, mind adding some explanation as well?

Comment: Which means that you need to _add this to your answer and explain the reason_. This is not an answer like this, this is just some random text thrown at the OP. I suggest you reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer